# New mainboard faulty?

Tags: boot, motherboard, fan, led

There is an issue with a new ASRock Z370 Extreme4 mainboard. It does not seem to switch on.

Both the 24pin and 8pin (CPU) power cables are plugged in.

The LEDs on the (Corsair 100R) case are not illuminated and the power button in the case does nothing when pressed.
A test with another type of mainboard revealed that the case LEDs, switches, and pins to the mainboard work just fine. The power supply (EVGA 750 GQ) should therefore be ok as well.

Is there a known incompatibility somewhere?
Do I need to plug in the CPU and RAM first to get any response at all? (besides the rytmically blinking, color changing ambient LED lights directly on the mainboard.) I tried that too, with no effect.

Did you ever experience a szenario like this or have a hint to what I could still try to make the mainboard work?
Thank you!

Comment: If you plug the CPU in you should get a beep code indicating no memory present.

Comment: How did you determine that it was safe to power up the motherboard without a CPU? Did the documentation say so?